# Strange array output?

Tags: list, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x=['a', 'b']
x=np.repeat(x,3)
x[0]="apple"
```

Why does my code produce `['a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b']` instead of `["apple" 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b']`?

Comment: The full `repr` display of your array shows the fixed-length `dtype`: `array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], dtype='<U1')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `numpy.repeat()` your list will contain type `numpy.str_` instead of `str`.
`numpy.str_`  is NumPy datatype used for arrays containing fixed-width byte strings. Check  `type(x[0])` and `type ("apple")` to see the difference.

Comment: `x.dtype` will be `U1`

Comment: I was confused now I understand thanks.